# Python3 can not find module xmlrpc from unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-import

I am working on a python project with 2 other people, but I can't run our tests. When I run the tests using `python3 -m unittest` I get this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Peer.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "Peer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
    from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
ImportError: No module named xmlrpc.client
ImportError: No module named xmlrpc.client
```

Line 1 in Peer.py is

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
```

The strange thing is that when I run Peer.py independently (`python3 Peer.py`) there are no problems. And it also works like a charm in the shell

```
Python 3.3.1 (v3.3.1:d9893d13c628, Apr  6 2013, 11:07:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xmlrpc.client
>>>
```

The 2 people I work with don't have any problems, and we are running the same code from version control. I get the same error on both OS X and Ubuntu, whereas they run Windows.

Comment: What does `print(xmlrpc.__file__)` or `print(xmlrpc.client.__file__)` print?

Comment: `xmlrpc.__file__` is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/xmlrpc/__init__.py`

Comment: And during the unit test? The file path indicates that you have the correct package at least, but during unit testing it appears something else is being loaded.

Comment: When I import xmlrpc.client and prints from the test file, it prints the same as in the previous comment. I can't print it from Peer.py as it fails before the import.

Comment: Then add `import xmlrpc.client` before the failing import and print the `__file__` there?

Comment: All imports regarding xmlrpc fails

Comment: Also plain `import xmlrpc`? Did you try to print `sys.path` when executing the tests?

Comment: Unfortunately `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3` is already in `sys.path`

Comment: @MathiasBak Reinstalling is an option? To me it seems that you either have a broken installation, or inside your project/somewhere you have a directory/module that the interpreter is trying to load instead of the stdlib module.